# Angular six set initial value for @Output EventEmitter

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-library

**I have a component**

```
     <p style="padding: 5px">

      <select [(ngModel)]='thisDD' name="nameDD" id="idDD" (ngModelChange)="updateDD(thisDD)" class="form-control">
        <option *ngFor="let thing of thingies" [value]="thing.thingID">{{thing.ThingName}} ({{thing.ThingCode}})</option>
      </select>  

     </p>
```

**Which has an @OutPut**

```
 @Output() selectedValue = new EventEmitter<object>();
```

**And I use this in my app**

```
<my-dropdown (selectedValue)="setValue($event)"></my-dropdown>
```

**Which calls code in the component to "setValue"**

```
setValue(event){
this.currValue=event;
}
```

This all works great when the value of the drop down is changed but I have other components that rely on a value being set 
when the application is loaded.

Is there a way to get the value I defaulted my component to through @Output?
or how would you accomplish this?

Comment: Boubble the event to the other componets with Input/Output if they are sibling, or a service (maybe with a subject)

Comment: Why can't you emit the default value in the `ngOnInit` method?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Simply emit the initial value in ngOnInit

```
export class YourClass {

    @Output() selectedValue = new EventEmitter<object>();

    ngOnInit() {
        this.selectedValue.emit({{your initial value}});
    }
}
```