# How to set initial value for Event Emitter

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an EventEmitter "action". How can I set the initial Value? For example it's always 'methodX' until I change it to 'methodY'..

Something like this:

```
export class FieldComponent {
  @Output() action: EventEmitter<any> = methodX;

  constructor() {
  }

  public methodX() {
  }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52598734/angular-six-set-initial-value-for-output-eventemitter

Comment: why you need that where action need pass from parent component?

Comment: I could not see any reason to assign a method and change in future, might be you will have some special case, could you please share the scenario? OR you mis-understood the EventEmitter...

Comment: @Nostix that's just an initial value **for the** EventEmitter-**Action**. I want an initial EventEmitter-**Action**...

Comment: What do you mean by "EventEmitter action"?

Comment: @AliAdravi well I have an Input-Field which focuses the next Input-Field. In the future I want to change the direction of the focusing (previous element), or await for something, ... Isn't it the right way?

Comment: @ConnorsFan in the linked question he tried to hand over an parameter to the action. But that's not my problem..

Comment: For just to change the order of tab you can simply use html attribute `tabindex`, event emitter are mostly used to get data from child to parent!

Comment: @AliAdravi it's not just to change the order. Another example is when finishing editing, I want to create a child element and after creation focus it. I'm pretty sure dealing with EventEmitter is the best way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can do this like you are wanting to. EventEmitter is just an abstraction of rxjs Subjects. If you use Subjects, you can use the BehaviorSubject and have an initial value, but the default Subject cannot.

Answer (score 0):

test this:

```
@Output() action: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();


ngOnInit() {
 this.action.emit({{initial value}});
 }

public methodX() {
console.log(action);
  }
```

Comment: like I said in the comments: this is for handing over a initial **parameter** to the action.